# Can't install apk in my device

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm building an Android app with Eclipse. If I try to deploy and start my application from Eclipse with my smartphone connected to the pc, I can use my application.

Now I want to build an `.APK` file from Eclipse. After I build it, I copy the .APK file to my device, so I use MyFiles app, search the .APK, click on it to install it but I have this stange error:

> Unfortunately, Package installer has stopped.

Now I don't know how can I fixed this. This is my mainfest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mcSolution"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mcSolution.main.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.mcSolution.main.nuovoOrdine"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.mcSolution.ordine.creaOrdine"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.mcSolution.ordine.mainOrdine"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.mcSolution.ordine.viewOrdine"></activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.mcSolution.setting.setting"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcSolution.articoli.viewArticoli"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcSolution.clienti.mainClienti"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcSolution.clienti.viewClienti"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcSolution.clienti.infoCliente"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcSolution.clienti.operazioniCliente"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcSolution.clienti.operazioniClienteDettaglio"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image]

Now if I try to copy my .APK file to a device running Android 4.0 I can install it without problems. If I try to install the same .APK on my smartphone with android 5.0.1, I have that error.

Comment: Your target version is 19, change it to 23 for lollipop or 25 for nougat. Make sure to add run time permissions if your target is 24 or above

Comment: I will recommend you to migrate to Android Studio, as gradle projects warn the developers in case of such mis matched configurations

Comment: I have try to change targetsdk from 19 to 23 but the problem is the same

Comment: If you are using an android version below 15 (honeycomb ,gingerbread) it will show the same error...try changing the min sdk version to 10 or 11 depending on your device's android version.

Comment: Some devices gives a pop up and ask for users active participation (Allow / Deny) to install an application from USB. I have found them in Xiaomi's two smartphones. (Apart from enable USB debugging)

Comment: You should check the logcat to see the real error why the package-manager crashes.